# Saving data with HABTM and HasMany looses foreignKey

Tags: cakephp, model, save, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a User model with two relations:

1. HasAndBelongsToMany

   ```
   public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
       'group' => array(
           'className' => 'group',
           'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
       )
   );
   ```
2. HasMany

   ```
   public $hasMany = array(
     'phonenumber' => array(
       'className' => 'phonenumber',
       'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
     )
   );
   ```

Phonenumber and Group have set

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
);
```

When I use

```
$this->saveAll(array(
            'User' => $data, 
            'phonenumber' => $numbers, //array with data
            'group' => $groups //array with data
   )
);
```

The data gets saved in the tabels but User_id is "0" in phonenumber and group table.

How can I get the correct ID saved ? (CakePHP v 2.5)

Comment: Can you please add the relevant data stored in the array's $data, $numbers & $groups?

Comment: it has normal user data like $data = array('name' => 'Jeff', 'country' => 'USA')

groups and phonenumber has data like array(array('number'=>'123 112'), array('number' => '321 321'))

Comment: I'm not sure if this has any consequences but your classnames are not spelled correct (case insensitive)

Additionally: Have you tried setting the foreignKey (user_id) in the Phonenumber & Group-Data?

Comment: To be clear: You want to add a new User and use it's auto incremented ID as user_id for the save of phonenumber and group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW saveAll() *should* work as advertised, populating the new user_id in the child tables in one fell swoop.

Have you paid attention to the relevant options: atomic & deep?

Especially if database does not support transactions, you'll need to pass in atomic:

```
$this->saveAll(array(
            'User' => $data, 
            'phonenumber' => $numbers, //array with data
            'group' => $groups //array with data
   ),
   array('atomic' => false)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the CakePHP documentation you will find this hint:

> When working with associated models, it is important to realize that
>   saving model data should always be done by the corresponding CakePHP
>   model. If you are saving a new Post and its associated Comments, then
>   you would use both Post and Comment models during the save operation
>   *(http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)*

Based on that information I suggest you try the following:

```
$this->User->save($data);  // first save the user
```

Assuming you have multiple numbers:

```
foreach($numbers as $key => $nbr) {
    // set user_id related data
    $numbers[ $key ]['Phonenumber']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;
}
```

Finally save your related data:

```
$this->User->Phonenumber->saveAll($numbers);
```

*Since this code is untested **you may need to take some adjustments**. Always ensure to follow the Cake-Conventions and use CamelCase ModelNames.*

Comment: Maybe your Bug is in your JavaScript.